# How to resolve InfoPath form Services in SharePoint?

Tags: 2007, infopath

I have created a form in InfoPath 2007 & Published it to our SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise. I have checked the InfoPath configuration, @ Central Admin, everything's fine.
Kindly check the E-Form image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?66dbb6c43c.jpg, that was the form I created, opened from clients browser, I test fill-up the form, send, at first time, it worked. Then I tried to fill-up & send again, by this time, I got the error (from the 2nd image, http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?e4ca5ec9f1.jpg). It says that I must check the error, check if I miss some "*" but I filled up everything, but I can't send anymore. I don't know know where to check, what to do next, etc. Kindly advise, do I need to refresh something or reset?

Second, how can I protect for the form that was approved already & list into the our IT Form library, other users can open it & delete or change some data inside. How to protect the data from other users?
Bec. if I set other users to be READ only, they can't open the form. The "NEW" will not be visible to users who are set to be READ only. So I set other users to be Contribute level, so the NEW will be visible, but the problem is they can do anything with the form that was created by other users too...

Please advise...

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in there you have rules that are not being met.  Do you have any hidden fields?

Typically when using InfoPath there is a workflow process created to run when the form is saved.  It is possible to change the form's permissions as part of that workflow with some custom code or 3rd party actions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't configured your form to save with a unique name.
The first screen in the data connection wizard allows you to configure the file name. You could use fields from the form to create a new unique file name.
In the same screen there is a tick box, this allows a file with the same name to be overwritten.
If you tick this then save and publish the form, then create a new form and submit. 
If the submit works then you know the problem is the form doesn't have a unique name.

I hope my answer is clearer than mud and useful.

I have just reviewed your screen shots, my answer may not be that useful afterall.

Hi Dan

Edit the form, go to Tools then select data connections. Select your Submit connection and modify.
I've highlighted in yellow the file name. In my example i've given the file name 'now' function, this will give the current date & time when the form is submitted. This way the file name will be always unique.

The example given within InfoPath shows a static name, in this case Status Report followed by field1 from the form itself.

[alt text http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/6600/dataconnectionsubmit.png](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/6600/dataconnectionsubmit.png)

Hi Dan

Apologies for the delay in getting back to you.
The file is overwriting itself becuase the file does not have a unique name when it is being saved and you probably have the 'Allow overwrite if the file exists' checked.

1. With your form navigate to the data connection wizard, file name. As shown in the screenshot. Click the function (*fx*) button at the end of the file name.
2. Click 'Insert Function..'
3. Under 'Categories' highlight 'Date and Time'.  On the right hand side under 'Functions highlight the 'now' function. Click OK twice.
4. Complete the data connection wizard and publish form as normal.

This will now give the form a unique file name everytime its submitted.

Let me know if this works for you.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

@Mike, I don't have any hidden fields. However, how will I know if I have any hidden fields? I just created the workflow @ SharePoint side, not with SharePoint Designer.

@profilesfrankodlive, honestly, I can't understand in which part do u mean? Could u please explain further & if possible, do u have any screenshots to follow the steps that you advise?

Hope to hear again...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@profilesfrankodlive, I did that, but then I encounter a problem, for example: 1st user filled-up the form, send it, then after that another users fill-up the form also, after they send the form, the 1st form that was stored in the form library was replaced by the succeeding forms sent. What I want to happen is not to replace the 1st form, but to create or list the other forms that was sent by users.

Please advise...